# Bug while fetching IPV6 addresses Java java.net.NetworkInterface

Tags: java

I tried fetching IPV6 address using the following:

```
Enumeration<NetworkInterface> interfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
while (interfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
  NetworkInterface iface = interfaces.nextElement();
  if (iface.isLoopback() && !includeLoopback || !iface.isUp()) {
    continue;
  }
  Enumeration<InetAddress> addresses = iface.getInetAddresses();
  while (addresses.hasMoreElements()) {
    InetAddress addr = addresses.nextElement();
    inetAddresses.add(addr.getHostAddress());
  }
}
```

This prints:
fe80:0:0:0:250:56ff:fe85:5cb2%eth0

When I do ifconfig it gives the below as ipv6 address as - 
fe80::250:56ff:fe85:5cb2/64

Where am I missing?
Help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: What is the expected output? Please note that you can shorten any amount of zeroes next to each other one time to `::`. So `fe80:0:0:0:250:56ff:fe85:5cb2` becomes `fe80::250:56ff:fe85:5cb2`. (notice the `::`)

Comment: This seem to be the same addresses except for the :: abbreviation. What would you expect as address?

Comment: I expected without %etho , guess I would do string manipulation to get rid of it :)

Answer (score 0):

IPV6 standart says:

::  equals :0:0:0:

Comment: Thanks but why /64 gets changed to %etho ?

Comment: @SamayraGoyal I suppose this is the adapter used.

Comment: /64 is the subnetmask and not the ip address. And eth0 is the network interface.

Comment: Thanks! This answers.